Can ansible roles or playbooks written in a single file?
Is there a way to define a role or a playbook as a single file. I have in most roles only a single directory with a single task file, which is often confusing.
I there a way to compact roles (even with a additional var directory) into a single file and then use this with ansible? The directory structure could be translated in an additional level of YAML structure?  I have the impression the abandoned jet project attempted something like this.
Alternatively, are there tools to take a single file and produce the role directory ansible expects?

Isn't it a duplicate of your own question from 3.5 years ago? A playbook is a single file by definition but for the roles, their behaviour (i.e. consider the difference between vars and defaults) depends on the file structure - and not much has changed since back then. I believe Jiří Baum's answer describes the best you could do in your situation - unless you can specify why do you need a role and not a task.

Indeed, I still worry about the same issue than years ago and hoped something would have changed. I have experimented with other Configuration Management systems recently and liked the way roles are code as readable documents. dhall has tools to convert compact descriptions in executable ansible (not tested). I hoped for a callable ansible function where a single file could define a role.

I mean, could you bring an example of a role that you would like to see as a single file but you don't want it to be a list of tasks with like vars defined on a block (which is literally the next level of precedence)? Another feature that roles have is an ability to store files or templates - there's no generic way to include them into a single YAML file, either (as multiline strings, unfortunately, don't solve everything).

What is your use case? Why do you need it to be a single file? What are you trying to achieve?

@AlexanderPletnev: After some more experimentation, I came to the conclusion you indicate: including that templates are not achievable outside of the file structure. I reduced and removed all unused files and things are a bit clearer, but still difficult to maintain.

@Andrew: I manage a family setup with 20 cpus on 3 locations. Most of my roles are relatively simple (few vars, a few task) and I think it would be easier to understand their interactions  if they were single files  and could be printed. I can see the ideas behind the current format but would appreciate an alternative structure (not a replacement) for simpler cases, which might Ansible gain additional users.
